# How do you map a dictionary to an existing pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to take the dictionary and use that to fill in missing values in a dataframe column.
So the dictionary keys correspond to the index in the dataframe or a different column in the data frame and the values in the dictionary correspond to the value I would like to update into the dataframe. Here's a more visual example.

```
    key_col  target_col
0       w      a
1       c      NaN
2       z    NaN
```

Dictionary I'd like to map into the dataframe

```
dict = {'c':'B','z':'4'}
```

I'd like the dataframe to look like

```
  key_col  target_col
0       w      a
1       c      B
2       z      4
```

Now I've tried a few different things. setting the index to key_col and then trying

```
df[target_col].map(dict)

df.loc[target_col] = df['key_col'].map(dict)
```

I know replace doesn't work because it requires I set a criteria on the values that need to be replaced. I would just like to update the value if the key_col/index has a data value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dict = {'c':'B','z':'4'}

#mask those that are not NaN in `target_col`
m=df.target_col.isna()
df.loc[m,'target_col']=df.key_col.map(dict)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

an alternative : changed name from dict to dicts to avoid confusion with the built-in type

```
df.set_index('key_col').T.fillna(dicts).T

           target_col
key_col 
   w         a
   c         B
   z         4
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1 (key_col as an additional column):**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#initial dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'key_col': ['w', 'c', 'z'], 'target_col': ['a', np.NaN, np.NaN]})
#dictionary/dict values to update - key value corresponds to key_col, value to target_col
update_dict = {'c':'B','z':'4'}

for key in update_dict.keys():
#df[df['key_col'] == key]['target_col'] = update_dict[] <-- Do NOT do this
df.loc[df['key_col']==key, 'target_col'] = update_dict[key]
```

This approach iterates through each key to be updated - checks if there is any location in the dataframe (df) where the key-to-be-updated (update_dict.keys() - key) exists. If a match exists, then the value in the target_col will be set to the updated value within the dictionary.

---

**Approach #2 (key_col as Index)**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['a', np.NaN, np.NaN], columns=['target_col'], index=['w', 'c', 'z'])
update_dict = {'c':'B','z':'4'}
for key in update_dict.keys():
df.loc[key, 'target_col'] = update_dict[key]
```

This approach is pretty self explanatory. Ensure that adequate error handling is provided in the event that the updated_dict contains a key that does not exist in the DataFrame, 
`df.loc[key, 'target_col']` will raise an exception.

---

Note: DataFrame().loc allows us to reference particular coordinates on the DataFrame using column labels, whereas .iloc uses integer based index labels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, but considering that you have a few samples, should not be a problem doing this:

```
x = x.set_index('key_col')
for k in dict.keys():
    x.loc[k] = dict[k] 
x.reset_index() # back to the original df
```

Comment: I kept getting an error saying"KeyError:  'target_column' is not in columns"

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply with a lambda function.

The example dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"key_col": {0: "w", 1: "c", 2: "z"}, "target_col": {0: "a", 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan}}
)
```

I renamed the dictionary as you should not use the name `dict` because it is a built-in object in Python.

```py
map_dict = {"c": "B", "z": "4"}
```

The use of `apply` and the lambda function.

```py
df.loc[:, "target_col"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: map_dict.get(x["key_col"], x["target_col"]), axis=1
)
```

`map_dict.get()` allows you to define a default value so we can use it to return the default `target_col` value for those rows which are not in the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update`, which modifies inplace, so no need to assign the changes back. Since pandas aligns on both index and column labels we'll need to rename the mapped Series so it updates `'target_col'`. (Rename your dict something else, like `d`).

```
df.update(df['key_col'].map(d).rename('target_col'))

print(df)
#  key_col target_col
#0       w          a
#1       c          B
#2       z          4
```

Answer (score 0):

As the column that has the `NaN` is `target_col`, and the dictionary `dict` keys correspond to the column `key_col`, one can use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`pandas.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) as follows

```
df['target_col'] = df['key_col'].map(dict).fillna(df['target_col'])

[Out]:

  key_col target_col
0       w          a
1       c          B
2       z          4
```